# Bézout's identity proof that if $(a,b,c)=1$ then $ax+bxy+cz=1$ has integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Massive edit to simplify the question. Some comments below might be made obsolete - specifically, the comment that this follows directly from Dirichlet. That was true for the original wording.

I'm looking for a short proof, directly from [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), of the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1:**
>   If $(a,b,c)=1$ then there exists an integer solution $x,y,z$ to $ax+bxy+cz=1$.

The case $(a,b)=1$ turns out to be equivalent to the theorem:

> **Theorem 2:** The natural map: $$\mathbb Z_{nm}^\times\to\mathbb Z_{n}^\times$$
>   is onto.

That's because "onto" means if $(a,n)=1$ then for some $y$, $a+ny\in\mathbb Z_{mn}^\times$, meaning that $(a+ny,m)=1$ and thus $1=(a+ny)x+mz=ax+nxy+mz$ has a solution. The converse is equally obvious.

The general case in the first theorem follows if we know the case when $(a,b)=1$ since, for general $(a,b)$, we have $\left(\frac{a}{(a,b)},\frac{b}{(a,b)}\right)=1$, so from the special case, we get:
$$\frac{a}{(a,b)}x_0 + \frac{b}{(a,b)} x_0y_0 + cz_0= 1$$
which implies:

$$ax_0 + bx_0y_0 + c((a,b)z_0)=(a,b)$$
Since $1=(a,b,c)=((a,b),c)$ we can find $(u,v)$ so that:
$$(a,b)u + cv = 1$$

We then get:

$$a(x_0u) + b(x_0u)y_0 + c((a,b)z_0u + v) = 1$$

So $(x,y,z)=(x_0u,y_0,(a,b)z_0u+v)$ is a solution for our original equation. (Thanks Patrick Da Silva for that reduction.)

I can easily prove Theorem 2 using the structure of $\mathbb Z_n^\times$ in terms of prime factorizations. Indeed, Theorem 2 was the motivation for this question, initially - at first I thought it was "obvious," but the immediately realized it wasn't absolutely trivial.

It's certainly possible to translate the "abstract" proof of Theorem 2 into a direct proof of the special case of Theorem 1 using prime factorizations and Chinese remainder theorem.

But something about this theorem rang a bell for me. It *looks* like the sort of theorem that would have a short Bezout's identity proof.

Both unique factorization and Chinese remainder theorem are actually direct results of Bézout, and often theorems that we intuitively understand in terms of unique factorization and/or Chinese remainder theorem have a short, sharp proof using Bézout that eschews both the words "prime" and "remainder."

My instinct is that there ought to be a quick proof of the above with Bézout, without calling out to primes or remainders, but I haven't found it.

It's trivial if $(a,c)=1$, since $ax+cz=1$ lets us use $y=0$ to get a solution to $ax+bxy +cz=1$.

It's a little harder to see if $(b,c)=1$, but still not hard, since if $bu+cv=1$ then $$a\cdot 1 + 1\cdot (1-a) = a\cdot 1 + b(u(1-a)) + c(v(1-a))$$ giving a solution $(x,y,z)=(1,u(1-a),v(1-a))$.

That asymmetry (it's easy to solve if $(a,n)=1$ and harder to solve if $(b,n)=1$) suggests I might be wrong about there being such a proof, since Bézout is such a symmetric statement.

If there was a proof, it seems like you ought to start with:

$$au+bv=1\\ax+ny=(a,n)\\bw+nz = (b,n)$$

---

As an example of a theorem that is "obvious" with unique factorization, but has a simple proof with Bézout's identity, consider:

> $(a,n)=(a,m)=1\implies (a,mn)=1$

That has a unique factorization proof, but it follows directly from Bézout by multiplying:
$$1=(ax_1+ny_1)(ax_2+my_2) = a(ax_1x_2 + mx_1y_2+nx_2y_1) + mn(y_1y_2)$$

---

So, again, the goal is to have nothing about primes or Chinese Remainder Theorem in the proof, and to have it be "remarkably brief" - as much as possible, it shouldn't be hiding proofs of CRT or unique factorization.

I don't know that such a proof exists, but some instinct told me it did.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Well, yes, but Dirichlet is a pretty powerful theorem. I'm looking for an extremely elementary proof. (I suspect most proofs of Dirichlet use this theorem somehow...)

Comment: And yes, this is now a very long question asking for a very short proof. :)

Comment: When there is only one commenter on a post, any comment by the poster is assumed to be a reply, so the commenter gets notified.

Comment: Perhaps it is true if $(a,b,n)=1$ that there is an $x,y,z$ with $x|y$ such that $ax+by+nz = 1$?

Comment: Can you prove that without the Bézout constraint? i.e. does the statement still hold if you relax $(a,b) = 1$ to $(a,b,n) = 1$?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews : Your last comment is possible because 
$$
(a+bk,n) = \left( (a,b) \left( \frac{a}{(a,b)} + \frac{b}{(a,b)} k \right),n \right) =  \underset{1}{\underbrace{((a,b),n)}} \left( \frac{a}{(a,b)} + \frac{b}{(a,b)} k,n \right),
$$
so it reduces to the case where $(a,b) = 1$ anyway.

Comment: So this makes it seem even more Bézout-y, since it is a statement about $(a,b,c)=1$ implying a solution to $ax+bxy+cz=1$. Although the asymmetry if the question is still the source of the mystery. @PatrickDaSilva

Comment: I tried to go back through the proof using CRT and I noticed this : if one chooses $x,y$ such that 
$$
bx + \frac{n}{(n,b^n)}y = 1,
$$
then taking $k$ such that $\left( k+ax, \frac{n}{(n,b^n)} \right) = 1$ should work (because it does in the CRT proof). The $(n,b^n)$ is just used to kill all the primes in $n$ that appear in the factorization of $b$. 

I tried a Bézout approach with such $k$ but I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Well, that approach allows you to do a descent proof - prove that if true for $(a,b,c/(b,c))$ then true for $(a,b,c)$. This lets you prove that if there is a counter-example, there is a counter-example with $(b,c)=1$. It's pretty obious this works, since the same $k$ works for $c/(b,c)$ that works for $c$. So descent proof works. @PatrickDaSilva

Comment: (I don't like a descent proof here, because it smells too much like prime factorizing, but it might be the best we can do.) @PatrickDaSilva

Comment: Yeah but I wanted to see what happens if we went through the CRT proof ; it seems like if there is such a Bézout proof it would require entirely new ideas, which I do not seem to have found after hours of work, so I let you to it. :)

Comment: Whoops, I'm wrong about the descent proof being "pretty obvious." @PatrickDaSilva

Comment: How do you mean? Work mod $p$ for all primes dividing $[n,b]$ and it's "pretty obvious", I thought that's what you meant. I don't know how to do it if we don't speak of primes though.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yeah, I meant without primes. If we were going to talk about primes, we'd be done already :)

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407383/if-a-b-c-1-is-there-n-in-mathbb-z-such-that-a-bnc-1/)?

Comment: @anon Nice, but those answers don't give the *type* of answer I'm seeking. There are certainly lots of proofs of this theorem.

Comment: I simply assumed the "type" of answer you were seeking was simply one that was short, minimal on assumptions and did not use prime factorization or CRT. I confess I am not interested in reading most of the question though, so my fault for being lazy. | Edit: "directly from Bezout's" hmm.

Comment: But all of those answers use primes and CRT. Or Dirichlet, which is definitely overkill. :) @anon

Comment: @Thomas My answer does not use CRT. It uses the (algebraic number theory version) definition of "prime," but it does not assume anything about factorization. | Edit: I am very bad at reading this morning, you just mentioned Dirichlet in your comment. :/

Comment: The "algebraic number theory defintion of prime" is proved equivalent to the normal definition of integer primes by unique factorization or one of its equivalents - it usually is proven from the lemma $$a|bc, (a,b)=1 \implies a|c$$ which is also the lemma for unique factorization. (That lemma is a direct result of Bézout, of course...)

Comment: And your proof uses other theorems about primes, such as there are only finitely many prime factors of an integer. That might seem obvious, but again, it's a fact about primes, and Bézout doesn't even need the definition of primes.

Comment: Heh, it's your question, you get to have it your way. :)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I'm having trouble with a much simpler result using Bézout only: If $(a,b)=1$ then $(a+b,ab)=1$. This would prove the above theorem for $c=ab$, since $(a+b)x+abz = 1$ implies $(x,1,z)$ is a solution to $ax+bxy+abz = 1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I removed the CW that got added since you edited this over 10 times. If you want me to put it back on, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, that would be nice. @robjohn Annoying, that, it discourages elaboration with further results, ideas.

Comment: Oh, of course, $(a+b,a)=1$ and $(a+b,b)=1$ means $(a+b,ab)=1$ by the usual proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be as simple as hoped, but it is pure Bezout.

We will use a couple of the results proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462179):
$$
(ac,bc)=c(a,b)\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
(a,b)=1\quad\text{and}\quad(a,c)=1\implies(a,bc)=1\tag{2}
$$
Furthermore, since $(a,b)\mid a$ and $(a,b)\mid bc$, we have
$$
(a,b)\mid(a,bc)\tag{3}
$$

---

**Lemma 1:** If $(a,b)=1$, then
$$
\begin{align}
1.&(a,n)(b,n)\mid n\\
2.&(a+b,a^mb^n)=1
\end{align}
$$
**Proof:** Suppose that $(a,b)=1$. Then for some $x,y$ we have
$$
ax+by=1\tag{4}
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\begin{align}
n
&=n(ax+by)\\
&=\left(\frac{n}{(b,n)}\frac{ax}{(a,n)}+\frac{n}{(a,n)}\frac{by}{(b,n)}\right)(a,n)(b,n)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
and therefore, we conclude that
$$
(a,n)(b,n)\mid n\tag{6}
$$
Furthermore, from $(4)$, we also have
$$
\begin{align}
1&=a(x-y)+(a+b)y&&(4)-ay+ay\tag{7}\\
1&=(a+b)x+b(y-x)&&(4)+bx-bx\tag{8}\\
\end{align}
$$
$(7)$ and $(8)$ say that $(a+b,a)=1$ and $(a+b,b)=1$. Repeatedly applying $(2)$ yields
$$
(a+b,a^mb^n)=1\tag{9}
$$
$\square$

---

**Lemma 2:**
$$
\left(a,\frac{n}{(a^n,n)}\right)=1
$$
**Proof:** Since $(a^k,n)\mid(a^{k+1},n)\mid n$, we must have, for some $k\le n$, that $(a^{k+1},n)=(a^k,n)$.

Suppose that $(a^{k+1},n)=(a^k,n)$. Then $\left(a\frac{a^k}{(a^k,n)},\frac{n}{(a^k,n)}\right)=1$ and therefore, $\left(a,\frac{n}{(a^k,n)}\right)=1$.

Since $k\le n$, we have $(a^k,n)\mid(a^n,n)$, and consequently,
$$
\left(a,\frac{n}{(a^n,n)}\right)=1\tag{10}
$$
$\square$

---

**Theorem:** If $(a,b)=1$, then
$$
\left(a+\frac{nu}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}b,n\right)=1
$$
where $u$ satisfies $(b,n)=bu+nv$.

**Proof:** Suppose that $(a,b)=1$ and $(b,n)=bu+nv$. Using $(2)$ repeatedly, we get
$$
(a^n,b)=1\tag{11}
$$
Combining $(6)$ and $(11)$ yield
$$
(a^n,n)(b,n)\mid n\tag{12}
$$
Thus, $\dfrac{n}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $(10)$ says that
$$
\left(a,\frac{n}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}(b,n)\right)=1\tag{13}
$$
$(9)$ and $(13)$ imply that
$$
\left(a+\frac{n}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}(b,n),a^n\frac{n}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}(b,n)\right)=1\tag{14}
$$
Since $(a^n,n)\mid a^n$, we have $\left.n\,\middle|\,a^n\dfrac{n}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}(b,n)\right.$, so using $(3)$ and $(14)$ yields
$$
\left(a+\frac{n}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}(b,n),n\right)=1\tag{15}
$$
The rest is Bezout. $(15)$ says that there are $x,y$ so that
$$
\left(a+\frac{n}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}(b,n)\right)x+ny=1\tag{16}
$$
Furthermore, since $(b,n)=bu+nv$, we get
$$
\left(a+\frac{nu}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}b\right)x+n\left(y+\frac{nv}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}\right)=1\tag{17}
$$
which just says that
$$
\left(a+\frac{nu}{(a^n,n)(b,n)}b,n\right)=1\tag{18}
$$
$\square$

---

**A note on application**

At first, $(18)$ may seem like a theoretical answer in the sense that it shows that we can find a $k$ so that $(a+bk,n)=1$, but computationally, it might appear a bit daunting due to the appearance of $(a^n,n)$ in the denominator. However, $n/(a^n,n)$ is simply $n$ with all the factors common to $a$ removed. To compute $n/(a^n,n)$, we can start with $n_0=n$, and generate the sequence
$$
n_{k+1}=\frac{n_k}{(a,n_k)}\tag{19}
$$
at some point $(a,n_k)=1$. For that $k$, we have
$$
\frac{n}{(a^n,n)}=n_k\tag{20}
$$

Comment: I'm starting to think exponentiation is needed, yeah. I'll take a bit to check this.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: the exponentiation is to be sure that we've taken all divisors of $a$ out of $n$, but at some point, this does require an iterated gcd. The actual exponent should not exceed $\lceil\log_2(n)\rceil$. $n$ is just to make sure.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: $(21)$ answers the question in the original form, but I see that $(20)$ answers the new form. Whew :-)

Comment: I don't think you need nearly that much work to prove that $(a^k,n)(b,n)|n$. Basically, you can prove if $(u,v)=1$ and $u|n$ and $v|n$ then $uv|n$. Then prove inductively that $(a^k,b)=1$ if $(a,b)=1$, so $(a^k,n)$ and $(b,n)$ are likewise relatively prime.

Comment: The statement before (3) indicates you conclude that $(a,b)|bc$ lets you conclude that $(a,b)|bc$. I don't think the proof needs to be so precise, in any event, that we need to prove that $(a,b)|bc$ in general.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I don't think what I did is any more work. I proved that $(a,b)=1\implies(a,n)(b,n)|n$ in $(5)$ and $(6)$, then simply used the result from [an earlier answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/462179) that $(a,b)=1\implies(a^n,b^n)=1$. Actually, if you stop the induction early, you get $(a^n,b)=1$, but I added one more step to get that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I simply wanted to prove $(a,b)\mid(a,bc)$ to show that it could be shown without FTA or mod. Depending on how much you want to assume, I am sure that this proof could be simplified. Actually, I think it might be possible to show that $(21)$ is true with less work. I just included the method I used to derive $(21)$. I might try to simplify this answer in a while.

Comment: It just gets very noisy when you have all those parentheses around, while the general theorem as a simple proof: If $ux+vy=1$ then $unx + vny = n$. Since $u|n$ and $v|n$, this means $uv|unx$ an $uv|vnx$ so $uv|n$. So the lemma is just less noisy.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I assume you are talking about formula after the second `=` in $(5)$. Before the overbraces, it was hard to tell what was going on, so I added the parentheses. Perhaps with the overbraces, the grouping parentheses might not be as necessary. Now that I look at it, the jump from the first to the third line may not be too big to make. I have deleted the second line.

Comment: I think it will be more readable as "lemma, lemma, ..., proof." For example $(a,b)=1$ implies $(a+b,a)=1$ and $(a+b,b)=1$, hence $(a+b,ab)=1$. Writing it out in long form all the way through makes it hard to wade through.

Comment: I added the horizontal ruling to break it into sections, but I can reorganize it. Lemma-Proof seems to make things longer.

Comment: As I often tell my coworkers about the programs, longer doesn't mean less clear. Lemma/proof can obscure things, and it will take some work to massage this into a Lemma/Proof argument that is clearer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: is this any more understandable?

Comment: I think this answer is perfect, if I can see why $\gcd(a^n,n)\mid a$. :)

Comment: @awllower: thanks for finding that. It should be fixed now.

Comment: I've posted an answer which I think is a distilled version of your proof. I'll probably check yours as "best answer" because most of the credit goes to you.

Comment: So that was not true! I did not realise that there was an error: I thought there must be something that I missed. Thanks for the response thus. :)

Comment: Whoops, forgot to select your answer until last night. I think your Lemma 2 and my Lemma 1 serve the same purpose, but perhaps my Lemma 1 is clearer. You are essentially using $(a^n,n)$ as my $n_2$, but the usage of $a^n$ seems a bit awkward and artificial. My proof of Lemma 1 is equally constructive, if perhaps a little less regular.

Comment: I've written what I think is a greatly reduced (and less noisy) proof. I guess I deeply dislike trying to keep track of all the fractions. It's at the end of my answer, starting at Lemma 5. It is definitely different from my answer, though obviously it still starts with factor $n=n_1n_2$.

Comment: One change would allow you to avoid dividing and multiplying by $(b,n)$. Just note that since $(b,n)\mid\dfrac{n}{(a^n,n)}$ then $bu+nv=\dfrac{n}{(a^n,n)}$ for some $u,v$. Slightly different $u,v$ than your answer, but same essential proof, and your expressions become less noisy.

Comment: @Rob Just discovered this Bezouka contest. I added an answer based on  an old idea of Stieltjes (that's basically what's at the heart of your answer too).

Answer (score 2):

Application of Chinese Remainder Theorem:

$$x\equiv a \textrm{ (mod $b$)}$$
$$x\equiv 1\textrm{ (mod $p$)}, \textrm{ for primes $p$ that divides $n$, but does not divide $b$}$$

Comment: This covers in general. $b$ and $n$ are not necessarily relatively prime. What we need is that primes dividing $n$ does not divide $x$.

Comment: In any event, it uses prime factorization and doesn't use Bezout's. I already know how to prove with CRT.

Comment: Well, you can formulate proof of CRT using Bezout's identity.

Comment: Yes, but then it wouldn't be a "short" proof. Unique factorization and Chinese Remainder Theorem both follow from Bézout, but quite a few theorems that seem to be about unique factorization or CRT have "short sharp" proofs directly from Bézout. That is what I'm looking for. I've updated my question to make that very clear.

Comment: Very interesting question. I'm giving it some thought.

Comment: The answer I came up with is substantially the same as yours, except I factored $n=n_1n_2$ with $(a,n_1)=(b,n_2)=(n_1,n_2)=1$, avoiding prime factorizations, and then hid the remainder theorem in large calculations. (The question got changes, so what in your answer are $n,x$ are $y,c$ in the altered question, but it is the same idea.)

Answer (score 2):

We use a constructive form of [Stieltjes method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647665/242) of constructing coprimes.

${\bf Theorem}\quad\ \ \ \color{#c0f}{(a,b,c)=1}\, \Rightarrow\, (a\!+\!bn,c) = 1\,\ $ for some $\,n\,$ that satisfies $\ \color{#c00}{(n,a)=1}$

$\require{cancel}{\bf Proof}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \phantom{1^{1^{1^{1^{1^{1^1}}}}}} \phantom{\dfrac{1}{1^{1^1}}} 
(a,c) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, \smash[t]{\overbrace{(a\!+\!bc,c)}^{\large (a,\,c)}=1.}\ $ Else induct on $c\!:\ $ $(a\!+\!bn,\color{#c70}{\large \frac{c}{(a,c)}})=1,\,$ $\, \color{#c00}{(n,a)\!=\!1},\,$
$(a\!+\!bn,\color{#0a0}{(a,c)}) = (bn,(a,c))=1\,$ by $\,\color{#c0f}{(b,a,c)}=1=(\color{#c00}{n,a},c)\ $ so $\ (a\!+\!bn,\color{#C70}{\large \frac{c}{\cancel{(a,c)}}}\!\color{#0a0}{\cancel{\small (a,c)}}\!)=1$

Answer (score 1):

A correct but imperfect answer, loosely based on the ideas in robjohn's answer.

**Lemma 1:** If $(a,b)=1$ then for any $n$, we can find $n=n_1n_2$ with $(n_1,n_2)=(a,n_1)=(b,n_2)=1$.

**Proof:** This requires induction. If $(n,a)=1$ then $n_1=n$ and $n_2=1$. Otherwise, let $m=\frac{n}{(a,n)}$. Then by induction $m=m_1m_2$ with $(m_1,m_2)=(m_1,a)=(m_2,b)$. But then let $n_1=m_1$ and $n_2=m_2(a,n)$. Since $(a,b)=1$, $((a,n),b)=1$, so $(n_2,b)=1$. So we're done.

[That assumes  $(x,z)=(y,z)=1\Rightarrow (xy,z)=1$, which is easy to prove with Bézout.]

---

**Theorem 1:** If $(a,b)=1$ then $\exists x,y.z: ax+bxy + cz=1$

**Proof:** By Lemma 1, we can write $c=c_1c_2$ with $(c_1,c_2)=(a,c_1)=(b,c_2)=1$.
Solve the following equations:

$$ c_1p + c_2q = 1\tag{1}$$
$$au_1+c_1v_1=1\tag{2}$$
$$bu_2+c_2v_2=1\tag{3}$$

Rewrite (3) as:
$$a\cdot 1 + bu_2(1-a) + c_2v_2(1-a)=1\tag{4}$$
Multiplying (2) by $c_2q$ and (4) by $c_1p=1-c_2q$ and adding, we get:

$$a(c_2qu_1 + 1-c_2q) + b(u_2(1-a)c_1p) + c_1c_2(v_1q+v_2p(1-a))=1\tag{5}$$

Letting $y=u_2(1-a)c_1p, x=c_2q(u_1-1)+1, z_0=v_1q+v_2p(1-a)$ we see that:

$$ax + by+ cz_0=1\tag{6}$$

And here's the magic: $$xy = c_2q(u_1-1)y + y = c_1c_2q(u_1-1)p(1-a)u_2 + y=cD+y\tag{7}$$

where $D=q(u_1-1)p(1-a)u_2$.

So $$ax + bxy + c(z_0-bD)=1$$This proves our theorem.

Not entirely satisfying, except for the fact that we have a systematic way to find $x,y,z$ for any $(a,b,c)$.

---

What is going on here? As noted in the question, if $(a,c)=1$ then $ax+cz=1$ has a solution, and $y=0$ gives us our solution.

If $(b,c)=1$, then solving $bu+cv=1$ which gives us a solution:

$$a\cdot 1 + b(u(1-a)) + c(v(1-a))=1$$
So above, we have essentially easy solutions to:

$$ax+bxy \equiv 1 \pmod {c_1,c_2}$$

and we are combining these easy solutions to these two equations in the way that Bézout's identity lets us prove Chinese Remainder Theorem.

The (not-really-so-magic) fact that $xy\equiv y\pmod {c}$ comes from the fact that $x\equiv 1\pmod {c_2}$ and $y\equiv 0\pmod {c_1}$.

Lemma 1 is essentially robjohns work about $(a^n,n)$, but in reverse. I think Lemma 1 is a more direct induction - exponentiation is artificial in this problem.

This proof is also pretty much exactly the same answer as i707107, who couched the answer in terms of prime factorization and Chinese Remainder Theorem.

---

**Related But Possibly Less Mysterious Proof**

There is a slightly more direct approach where we can prove a more specific theorem:

**Theorem 3:** If $(a,b)=1$ then for any $c$ we can find $x,y,z$ so that:

$$ax+by+cz = 1\\ c\mid xy-y$$

Note: Theorem 3 clearly implies Theorem 1. It is not transparent that Theorem 1 implies Theorem 3.

**Proof of Theorem 3:**

As noted before, when $(a,c)=1$ we can find a solution to the linear equation with $y=0$. If $(b,c)=1$, we can find a solution with with $x=1$. In both cases, $xy-y=0$ so the second condition is true.

So all we need to show is that if $(c_1,c_2)=1$ and we have solutions:

$$ ax_i+by_i+c_iz_i=1\\c_i\mid x_iy_i-y_i$$

for $i=1,2$, then we can find a solution:

$$ax+by+c_1c_2z = 1\\ c_1c_2\mid xy-y$$

The direct way to combine the linear equations just works. Solve $c_1u+c_2v=1$ and choose:

$$x = c_2vx_1 + c_1ux_2\\y=c_2vy_1 + c_1uy_2\\z=z_1v+z_2u$$

To get  $c_1c_2$ we multiply the first linear equation by $c_2v$ and the second by $c_1u$ and add to get a linear equation for $a,b,c_1c_2$.

Now you just need to verify that $xy-y$ is divisible by $c_1c_2$. This can be done by painful calculation. The big trick is using that $(c_1u)^2 = c_1u(1-c_2v) = c_1u - c_1c_2(uv)$ and likewise that $(c_2v)^2 = c_2v - c_1c_2(uv)$. This lets you get that $xy = c_2vx_1y_1 + c_1ux_2y_2 + c_1c_2D$ for some $D$. But then $x_iy_i-y_i$ divisible by $c_i$ means that we can write this as: $xy = c_2vy_1 + c_1uy_2 + c_1c_2D_2 = y + c_1c_2D_2$, for some $D_2$.

Essentially, the reason that $c_1c_2\mid xy-y$ is that $x$ and $y$ are the formulas for the Chinese remainder theorem, so $x\equiv x_i\pmod {c_i}$ and hence $c_i\mid xy-y$ for each $i$. But you can avoid appeals to the remainder theorem by just working it out and proving that $c_1c_2|xy-y$.

Once you have this result, you can use Lemma 1 above to prove the general result for all $c$.

One last comment. Lemma 1 actually is easily generalized to:

**Lemma 2:** If $(a,b,c)=1$ then there exists a factoring $c=c_1c_2$ with $(c_1,a)=(c_2,b)=(c_1,c_2)=1$.

**Proof:** Letting $a'=\frac{a}{(a,b)}$ and $b'=\frac{b}{(a,b)}$ we apply Lemma 1 to $a',b',c$ we get $c=c_1c_2$ with $(c_1,c_2)=(a',c_1)=(b',c_2)=1$. But then since $((a,b),c_1)=1$ and $(a',c_1)=1$, we hve that $(a,c_1)=1$. Similarly for $b$. This requires the Lemmas:

**Lemma 3**: If $(a_1,c)=(a_2,c)=1$ then $(a_1a_2,c)=1$.

**Proof**: This is easily proved from Bézout by multiplying the two equations $a_ix_i+cy_i=1$ for $i=1,2$.

**Lemma 4**: If $(a,b)=1$ and $c\mid b$ then $(a,c)=1$.

**Proof**: Again, easy to prove from Bézout's - if $c=bd$ then $1=ax+by=ax+c(dy)$.

Lemma 2 means that we can remove the condition that $(a,b)=1$ in our theorems - we only used that condition to factor $c$ via Lemma 1.

---

**Robjohn's proof, simplified**

Robjohn's answer can be summarized as follows:

**Lemma 5:** If $(a,b,n)=1$ then there exists an $n_1$ such that the following conditions hold:
$$(a+n_1,n)=1\\(b,n)\mid n_1\mid n$$

**Proof:** Induction on $n$.

If $(a,n)=1$ we can choose $n_1=n$ since $(a,n)=1\Rightarrow (a+n,n)=1$ and $(b,n)\mid n$.

If $(a,n)>1$ write $n=(a,n)m$, and find $m_1$ so that $(a+m_1,m)=1$ and $(b,m)\mid m_1\mid m$. . Writing $$1=(a+m_1)x + my = ax + m_1\left(x+\frac{m}{m_1}y\right)$$, we see that $(a,m_1)=1$.

Let $n_1=m_1$. Then, $(a,n_1)=(a,m_1)=1$, and we can conclude that $(a+n_1,a)=1$ so $(a+n_1,(a,n))=1$. So $$(a+n_1,n)\mid (a+n_1,(a,n))\cdot(a+n_1,m)=1$$

Finally, we can easily see that, since $(a,n)=1$, that $(b,n)=(b,m)$. So $(b,n)=(b,m)\mid n_1=m_1\mid m\mid n$.

---

**Theorem:** If $(a,b,n)=1$ then there exists an $x,y,z$ so that $ax+bxy+cz=1$.

**Proof:** Let $n_1$ be as in Lemma 5. Then we can find solutions to:
$$bu+nv=n_1\\(a+n_1)x+nz=1$$

Replacing $n_1$ in the second, we get:
$$(a+bu)x + n(z+xv)=1$$

---

This is the heart of robjohn's solution, but it avoids exponentiation in the argument, and minus all the fractions. Essentially, $n_1=\frac{n}{(a^n,n)}$, but those details are noisy for the rest of the proof, while these are the only properties we really need for $n_1$ and we can prove that by induction directly.

Comment: Neither my proof nor robjohn's avoids factorizing, but, once simplified as above, I think robjohn's is cleaner. I've skipped proving some easy lemmas, like: $$(a,mn)\mid (a,m)(a,n)$$ $$(a,n)=1\Rightarrow (a+n,a)=1$$ Maybe a few others. These have classical Bézout identity proofs.

Comment: With my simplification, it is clear where my proof at the top and robjohn's differ - I have a less stringent requirement on $n_1,n_2$, while robjohn's proof picks a very specific $n_1,n_2$. This makes the rest of his proof fairly direct, while mine has to go through hoops that are essentially Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: Note also that my **Lemma 5** doesn't actually require that $(a,b)=1$. The proof works just as well for $(a,b,n)=1$. That's because we just need $(b,(a,n))=(a,b,n)=1$. So this proof handles the general case directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found an excellent short proof.

**Theorem 1:** If $(a,b,c)=1$ then there exists $x,y,z$ so that $$ax+bxy+cz=1$$.

**Proof:** Induction on $c$ and $b$.

We can solve if $b=1$ by setting $(x,y,z)=(1,(1-a),0)$.

Now, assume that, for some $c$ we can solve for $(a,b,c')$ if $c'<c$ and $(a,b',c)$ if $b'<b$.

Then we break this up into two cases.

**Case 1**
If $b\not\mid c$, then $(b,c)<b$ and, by the induction hypothesis, we can solve:

$$ax+(b,c)xy+cz =1$$
and
$$bu+cv=(b,c)$$

Then $$ax +bx(uy) + c(z+vxy)=1$$

**Case 2**
If $1<b\mid c$, then $1=(a,b,c)=(a,b)$. Let $c=bd$.

Since $d<c$ and $(a,b,d)|(a,b,c)=1$, we can solve:

$$ax+bxy + dz=1$$

That can be seen as saying that $(a+by,d)=1$. But from $(a,b)=1$, we can see that $(a+by,b)=1$. So this means that $(a+by,c)=(a+by,db)=1$. And then we can find a solution to $$(a+by)X+cZ=1$$

(We could be more explicit in that last step: If $au+bv=1$ then $(a+by)u + b(v-yu)=1$. Multiplying that by $(a+by)x+ dz=1$ gives us an explicit solution to $(a+by)X + bdZ=1$.)

---

The trick here in case (1) was in robjohn's proof - he solved for the triple $(a,(b,c),c)$ first, then used that to show there was a solution for the triple $(a,b,c)$. I've just pushed that trick into the descent part of the proof.

This hides the "factoring" part of the proof. We are certainly essentially factoring out the parts of $c$ that are common with $b$ in the descent, but it feels more organic.

An interesting fact about this proof is that the new $y$ we get via induction is always the same $y$ or $yu$. Since $a$ doesn't change in the induction, and $y=1-a$ when $b=1$, this means that the $y$ we get from this proof is always divisible by $a-1$.

Comment: Another way to show $\,(a+bn,c) = 1\,$ for some $\,n\,$ is to cancel factors of $\,a\,$ from $\,c,$ to reduce the the trivial case when $\,(a,c)= 1,\,$ where $\,n = c\,$ works. This amounts to choosing $\,n\,$ to be the largest factor of $\,c\,$ coprime to $\,a.\,$ In my answer I give an induction that essentially computes that, by continually cancelling $\,(a,c)\,$ from $\,c.\ $ (I only stumbled upon your question just now). $\ \ $

Comment: Would it be correct to interpret your constraints as saying that you desire a proof that works in any Bezout domain? If so, then this is closely related an open problem (which explains the difficulty you had in finding a pure Bezout-based proof). I plan to update my answer shortly, but I thought it would be helpful to first get some feedback from you on the constraints.

Comment: @BillDubuque I would be interested if you develop the difficulties of a just Bézout proof for this question

Comment: @BillDubuque May I ask whether such statement holds in all Bezout domain? As [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647642) suggests, first we have to prove for any (nonzero) $c$, there exists an element that is coprime with $c$, which seems to me not that straightforward to prove it in any Bezout domain