# Existence of integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ be three integers whose greatest common divisor is $1$ (ie $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$). Show that there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $a+mc$ and $b+nc$ are coprime.

Progress: I believe the question is essentially asking us to show that it's always possible to find integers $p$ and $q$ and $s$ such that $pa+qb+sc=1$, and $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

---

**Added Context**

[This related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463052) indicates that this problem requiring $n=0$, is more complex. This question, by not requiring $n=0$, might allow simpler solution.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: It may also be good to write explicitly $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, so in particular $\gcd(a,b)$ could be anything.

Comment: [This related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463052/bézouts-identity-proof-that-if-a-b-c-1-then-axbxycz-1-has-integer-solut) indicates that the related problem, requiring $n=0$, is more complex. This question is related, but allows a far simpler solution by not requiring $n=0$. This is an interesting question and I think it should be reopened.

Comment: Technically, my old question isn't *that* hard, it was just using the condition of avoiding a unique factorization proof that made it hard. The old question does appear to require some sort of descent argument, however. @robjohn

Answer (score 2):

Bezout says there are $x,y$ and $u,v$ so that $ax+by=(a,b)$ and $(a,b)u+cv=1$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
&(a+yc)\left(ux+\frac{bv}{(a,b)}\right)+(b-xc)\left(uy-\frac{av}{(a,b)}\right)\\
&=\color{#600000}{a\left(ux+\frac{bv}{(a,b)}\right)+b\left(uy-\frac{av}{(a,b)}\right)}\\
&+\color{#005000}{yc\left(ux+\frac{bv}{(a,b)}\right)-xc\left(uy-\frac{av}{(a,b)}\right)}\\[6pt]
&=\color{#600000}{(a,b)u}+\color{#005000}{cv}\\[12pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
(a+yc,b-xc)=1
$$

Comment: Nice direct Bezout proof. You can just write it as $(a+yc)b-a(b-xc)=c(a,b)$. Dividing by $(a,b)$, we see that the gcd of $a+yc$ and $b-xc$ is a divisor of $c$. But if $p$ divides $c$ and $a+yc$ and $b-xc$ then $p\mid (a,b,c)$.