# Is the assertion about the form $\alpha x+\beta xy+\gamma y$ true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

In [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407383/if-a-b-c-1-is-there-n-in-mathbb-z-such-that-a-bnc-1/477059#477059), I was led to conjecture the following:

> **Statement:**
>   If $\gcd(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=1,$ then every integer can be written as $\alpha x+\beta xy+\gamma y$ for integer $x$ and $y$.

If the above is true, my original question would be solved, but the validity of the original question does not imply the truth of the above assertion.
And what I can think about now is that this is just Bézout's identity, in the case $\beta=0$.
Thanks for any help, and, please, localise each inappropriate point that takes place here.

Comment: I wonder if this is true when $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ all have a pairwise GCD of 1.

Comment: @Ryan See the example by Robert Israel: the $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ there are pairwise coprime, but the assertion is still false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\alpha x + \beta x y + \gamma y = z$ means $(\alpha + \beta y) x = z - \gamma y$
so either $z - \gamma y = 0$ (in which case you could take $x=0$) or
$\alpha + \beta y \ne 0$ and $z - \gamma y$ is divisible by $\alpha + \beta y$.
But then $\beta (z - \gamma y) + \gamma (\alpha + \beta y) = \beta z + \alpha \gamma$ must also be divisible by $\alpha + \beta y$.  Suppose e.g. $\beta z + \alpha \gamma$ is a prime $P$.  Then $\alpha + \beta y$ can only be
$\pm 1$ or $\pm P$.
Now $P \equiv \alpha \gamma \mod \beta$, while $\alpha + \beta y \equiv \alpha \mod \beta$.  So if $\alpha$ is not congruent to $\pm 1$ or $\pm \alpha \gamma$ mod $\beta$, you're out of luck.

For example, take $\beta = 7$, $\gamma = 2$, $\alpha = 3$,$z=1$ (so $P = 13$).

Comment: Thanks for this simple answer: it told me that simple congruence-considerations could rule out the solvability of this equation. So my conjecture is plain wrong... Thanks again. :P

Comment: From this calculation we can even deduce that, if $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)=1,$ then a sufficient condition for the solvability is that $\alpha+\beta y\mid \alpha\gamma+\beta z.$

Comment: An amusing but not surprising fact: Denote $\alpha\gamma+\beta z=n_1, \alpha+\beta y=n_2.$ Then $n_2\equiv \alpha\pmod \beta, n_1\equiv \alpha\gamma\pmod\beta.$ So $(n_2\mid n_1)\implies \exists k\in\mathbb Z, (\alpha+\beta y)(\gamma+\beta k)=(\alpha\gamma+\beta z)\implies \alpha k+\gamma y+\beta yk=z$. Namely, this condition is really equivelent with our original equation.

Answer (score 3):

This is false.
$\gcd(6,15,10)=1$, but there is no integer solution to
$$6x+15xy+10y=1 $$

You can verify this easily by finding condition for $6x+15xy+10y>0$ and finding the local minima in those areas.

Thanks to chubakueno :

$$6x+15xy+10y+4=5 $$

$$(3x+2)(5y+2)=5 $$

So $(5y+2)$ must divides $5$, this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting counter-example!

Comment: A proof that may be simpler: $6x+15xy+10y=1 \iff (3x+2)(5y+2)=5 \implies 5y+2|5 \implies 2|5$.Contradiction.

Comment: @chubakueno I think your last step could be modified: $$5y+2\mid 5\implies 5y+2\mid (5y+2)-5y=2\implies y=0\implies 2\mid 5.$$ Of course the key is the factorisation. :b