# Is this "by symmetry" statement valid?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Problem: Let $p,q,r$ be integers such that $\gcd(p,q,r)=1$. Prove that there exists an integer $A$ such that $\gcd(p,q+Ar)=1$.

A start: Assume for the sake of contradiction that $\gcd(p,q+Ar)>1$ for all integers $A$. Therefore, **by symmetry** we also have $\gcd(q,r+Ap)>1$ for all integers $A$.

My reasoning for this: Assume for contradiction that $\gcd(p,q+Ar)>1$ and $\gcd(q,r+Ap)=1$. Then since there is nothing special about this we can infer that it is possible for $\gcd(p,q+Ar)=1$ and $\gcd(q,r+Ap)>1$ to hold. But then this makes the original problem undetermined, because we can have either $\gcd(p,q+Ar)=1$ for some integer $A$, or $\gcd(p,q+Ar)>1$ for all integers $A$.

Is this valid? Thanks.

Comment: Cf. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407383/if-a-b-c-1-is-there-n-in-mathbb-z-such-that-a-bnc-1). Also, I don't think that argument by symmetry holds, as your assumption is that there exists a specific pair $(p,q,r)$ such that $\gcd(p,q+Ar)\gt1, \forall A\in\mathbb Z,$ while you haven't shown that $(q,r,p)$ is such a pair as well.